# XNA 4 and External References

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I was trying to implement something similar to the External References sample on Shawn Hargreaves blog

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/08/12/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-intermediateserializer.aspx

The problem I have is that when VS try to compile the xml file, it throws an error like

> Error 1   Building content threw ArgumentException: External reference "C:\Work\Company\Project\trunk\Project.Content\Sprites\Effects\EffectsSprite.tga" is not a compiled .xnb file.
>      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Compiler.ContentWriter.WriteExternalReference[T](ExternalReference`1 reference)
>      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Compiler.ExternalReferenceWriter`1.Write(ContentWriter output, ExternalReference`1 value)
>      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Compiler.ContentTypeWriter`1.Write(ContentWriter output, Object value)
>      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Compiler.ContentWriter.InvokeWriter[T](T value, ContentTypeWriter writer)
>      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Compiler.ContentWriter.WriteObject[T](T value)
>      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Compiler.ContentWriter.WriteSharedResources()
>      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Compiler.ContentWriter.FlushOutput()
>      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Compiler.ContentCompiler.Compile(Stream output, Object value, TargetPlatform targetPlatform, GraphicsProfile targetProfile, Boolean compressContent, String rootDirectory, String referenceRelocationPath)
>      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.SerializeOutputAsset(BuildItem item, Object assetData, String outputFilename)
>      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.SerializeAsset(BuildItem item, Object assetData)
>      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.BuildAssetWorker(BuildItem item)
>      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.BuildAsset(BuildItem item)
>      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.RunTheBuild()
>      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Tasks.BuildContent.RemoteProxy.RunTheBuild(BuildCoordinatorSettings settings, TimestampCache timestampCache, ITaskItem[] sourceAssets, String[]& outputContent, String[]& rebuiltContent, String[]& intermediates, Dictionary`2& dependencyTimestamps, KeyValuePair`2[]& warnings)   C:\Work\Company\Project\trunk\Project.Content\Sprites\Effects\AtlasAuto.xml Project

What am I supposed to do with the file referenced by the Xml file? Given it's on the same folder as the xml file, 
I have tried to:

1. include in the content project and process it with Texture - XNA Framework,
2. exclude it from the project and
3. do not build the file but simply copying it over as content...

Nothing seems to work. I wonder if that example does work in XNA4 or if it was for XNA3 and they changed the way this works on XNA4...

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Tough to say without seeing the XML and project layout, but I believe it may be this:

> Your approach looks good, but the problem is you also need to build this texture file.  An ExternalReference can point either to a source file (such as a .jpg or a .fx), or alternatively it can point to a compiled .xnb file.  Typically you will want the data going in at the start of the pipeline to be pointing to source files, but the data coming out the other end needs to point to compiled .xnb files, so these can be loaded into your game.
>   The most common way to accomplish this is using a custom processor that takes in the reference to a source asset, asks for this asset to be compiled, and changes the reference to point to the resulting compiled version of it. For instance (in the processor):
>   `material.Texture = context.BuildAsset<TextureContent, TextureContent>(material.Texture, "TextureProcessor");`

Referenced here (in the second post):
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/44917.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that external references within xml content cannot point to source assets.

1. Make sure the item being referenced is also included in the content project.
2. Do not include the file extension in its name.
3. Its path should be relative to the location of the xml file (I am not 100% certain, if this does not locate it also try relative to the root of the content project).